# Adding the notification icons to the blog

Tags: discussion, feature-request, superuser-blog

My home page is the [Super User Community Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/)

When I launch Chrome, I like to read the blog and to see if I have new notifications.

Unfortunately, the notification icon are not in the bar, so I must navigate in other part of the site to check them.

[image]

I suggest to add the notification icons to the navigation bar of the Super User Community Blog.

Comment: Wow, your *homepage* is set to a site that's only updated once every few *years*? That's a staggeringly impressive compliment to the SU blog... I'm sure @nhinkle will be eager to hear of your praise for the blog ;)

Comment: I'm a new user and I didn't know that the blog was not updated :(
This is sad... However, I think the idea is still good and might encourage the community to update it.

Comment: kronos more than anyone, :P @allquixotic

Comment: @Galabyca http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room Would you like to contribute? :D

Comment: I would be really happy to contribute !

Comment: Thanks to this question I noticed **[this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277954/site-switcher-favicon-broken-across-all-blogs)**.

Comment: Well... Now I feel bad that I've let this blog grow stagnant.

Comment: Also, I'm not an employed developer, so I'm not officially stating this, but I believe that the Superuser blog is hosted on a different and separate server and may not have the ability to add this feature.